# Getting started with multivariate testing

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, experiment-design

I'm looking for the best combination of variables to result in a click to the next page of my website... For example the size and color of a submit button.

I have a system that currently tests each variable independently to find the best value for that variable.

I would like to take the next step to testing combinations of these variables.

I'm looking for help with 2 steps in this process:

1. How to save the result sets - Currently I store each variable independently in mysql with no link to the other variable values that were tested.  What are some best practices for recording this data (schema design)?
2. How to analyze the result sets - Stats is not my strong suit, and I don't have any previous experience with stats software... I'd like a more-or-less black-box type of approach....  I supply the raw data (from step 1) and the analysis software spits back out to me the best combination of optimized variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are times when the black box resides inside the head of a statistical consultant.   To go from zero experience with stat. software to conducting sound, insightful multivariate analysis is a bit of a jump.  The best practices you're looking for might be contained in, oh, 15 or 20 of the threads on this site, but the question is whether you have the time and the will power to search for them and to struggle with the ideas enough to be ready to do the analysis as effectively as you really want it done.

Comment: I've taken your advice, and posted this on odesk in search of consultants.  If your interested, it's here: https://www.odesk.com/jobs/~~4e7480958aecbac5

Comment: Thanks for sharing that.  I'm surprised to see so many of the hourly rates there falling in the teens and 20s.  The statistical consultants with which I'm familiar (including moi) charge $50-150/hour.

Comment: @rolando2 Welcome to the world of differential purchasing power parity.

Comment: Actually, I know of several hundred consultants who charge nothing for their work :-).